# Can I fill out an input field and click on a submit button which are not in the form?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I need to fill out the Zipcode field and submit it afterwards I need to follow the response url. Anyone please help , I am confused if I can do it through mechanize python? Or just with python ?

```
<div id="zipHorizontal" class="zipIn zipIn-error">

    Enter <b>ZIP code</b> to see price.
    <input type="text" max="5" name="zipcode_lst" maxlength="20" class="error">
    <button type="submit" class="button secondary"><span>Submit</span></button>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts to solve it? If yes, show the code you have at the moment and what problems do you have.

Answer (score 0):

u/alecxe is correct.  you should likely provide information about what you've tried thus far.

given the simplicity of what you've described (as I understand it), I would recommend using [Robobrowser](http://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), as it relies on well-documented and supported Python libraries ([Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and thus is usually easier (for beginners like me and you).

The following code might work for you.  Give it a shot!

```
# create browser instance & open url
browser = RoboBrowser(history=False)
browser.open(your_url)
# get form
your_form_variable = browser.get_form(your_form_id="create_event")
# complete form
your_form_variable ["zipcode_lst"] = zip_to_be_submitted #string or int?
# submit form & log out
browser.submit_form(your_form_variable)
browser.logout()
```

That should do it.  Please edit your response to explain what you've tried thus far and feel free to follow up with any questions.  Good luck!!